# How can I define syntax for a binder with an additional argument in Isabelle?

Tags: syntax, isabelle

I want to define a syntactic construct in Isabelle that has the form `c ? x. p` where `c` and `p` are values and `x` is a variable. This construct should translate to `Input c (λx. p)`. It seems that this cannot be done via a `binder` annotation, since this construct has an additional argument `c` and furthermore cannot bind multiple variables. How can I define such a construct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using the low-level `syntax` and `translations` facilities. Assuming that `c` is of a type `channel`, `p` and `Input c (λx. p)` are of a type `process`, and the desired precedence is 100, the construct can be defined as follows:

```
syntax
  "_Input" :: "channel ⇒ pttrn ⇒ process ⇒ process"
  ("(3_ ? _./ _)" [101, 0, 100] 100)
translations
  "c ? x. P" ⇌ "CONST Input c (λx. P)"
```

These kinds of syntax definitions are described in Subsection 8.2.1 of the Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual. To understand the above solution, it might be helpful to also look at Subsections 8.2.2 and 8.2.3, which partly explain how the more high-level `infix`, `infixl`, `infixr`, and `binder` constructs can be translated into low-level definitions. In addition, a look at the definitions of the set comprehension constructs in `$ISABELLE_HOME/src/HOL/Set.thy` could be useful.